# How to edit wordpress theme contact page contents

Tags: php, html, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Need some help with a wordpress theme contact page content.

Am trying to edit it directly from source, it seems to show as a html file. I understand that wordpress runs on php so I've searched quite a number of php files but none include the contents which is showing in the image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1zao.jpg

Read a bit more online and some said that it's saved in the database. Been trying to find it in phpmyadmin too but without much luck. Maybe I'm not looking good enough.

I'm also trying to remove the entire block of code below from the website hakataai.com :

div class="sc_form_address column-1_3"

Please advise if anyone has any ideas.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either search again in your sources because the file is there or you can do one of the following:

1)If you want to remove completelly some content try to use custom css and `display: none;` your element.

2)If you want to change your content to something else you can also use css (for text purposes i suggest it) and use the `:after` tag, to display something different on your element.

i.e.: let's say the class you want to change is the `sc_form_subtitle`:

1) `h6.sc_form_subtitle{ display: none;}` (will hide the element)

2) `h6.sc_form_subtitle::before{ display: none;}
   h6.sc_form_subtitle::after{content: " type your text";}`

Answer (score 0):

try inspect element on item it will show you the exact place on the code, then go to your filemanager from host view and edit it however you want